# Check if object contains only empty nested objects

Tags: javascript

`lodash.isEmpty([{}])` returns `false` even though the object contained in the array is empty.

I need something that considers these kind of nested objects empty too and wrote the below recursive function. It looks a bit ugly and doesn't use any `JavaScript` specific tricks. Any comments welcome.

```
export function isDeepEmpty(input) {
  // catch null or undefined object
  if (!input) return true
  if (typeof(input) === 'object') {
    for (const entry of Object.values(input)) {
      if (!isDeepEmpty(entry)) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  // if input is not an object return false
  return false
}
```

Comment: You return `true` if any item is `!= true` eg `isDeepEmpty([0])` and  which to me seams wrong, Could you be more specific in regards to what you mean by empty.

Comment: Good point, thanks very much! Let me think more.

Comment: It appears [lodash](https://lodash.com) is an utility library, and this is where your [isEmpty()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEmpty) function comes from. It tests for quite a lot of things. You seem to want to extend its capability. In that case I would expect you to use this `isEmpty()` function inside your `isDeepEmpty()` function. Why don't you? Please note that **Code Review** is only for code that is _actually working_. It says so in the [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) box, when you ask a question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Your comment was very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @M3RS Was that cynical or serious? I can't tell. Perhaps that is the intention? Well, let's assume it was serious. If you have solved your own question you can answer your own question. There's nothing wrong with that. After all, SO is a place for people to learn from others. Your question is still unanswered, so your answer would be welcomed. Don't forget to _review_ your code.

Comment: No, sorry, it was serious. It was a v good point that maybe I should build this around `lodash.isEmpty()`, so extend it. Also, I understand that the could should be working.

Comment: Is an object empty if it contains values that are empty arrays? I suspect @Blindman67 misinterpreted this, since your example loops values of an object.

Comment: Arrays are objects, so `Object.values(array)` can be used to loop through array items.

Comment: Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1

Answer (score 4):

### Some issues?

- `typeof` is not a function. eg `typeof(input) === 'object'` is written `typeof input === 'object'`
- `null` is an `Object` so when you test for an object using `typeof` you MUST make sure it is not `null` as well.
- The test that you comment as `// catch null or undefined object` will catch any value that evaluates to a falsey, such as `false`, `0`, `""`

### What is empty?

As it is unclear what you define as empty so I will make some assumptions, they are arbitrary and may or may not fit your needs.

1. An array is empty if it contains only empty items.
2. An object is empty if it is `null` or contains no own properties. If it has properties that are `null` or (defined as) `undefined` it is not empty.
3. A string is empty if it contains no characters
4. Empty items are `null`, `undefined`, `{}`, `[]`, and `""`

#### Examples

Empty

```
[], 
{}, 
[undefined],
[null],
[[], [], []], 
[{},,[],[[[null],[undefined]],[,,,,,]],
new Array(10),
null,
undefined,
""
```

Not empty

```
[0]
[{A:null}], 
{A:undefined}, 
[,,,0],
[[], [], [1]], 
[{},,[],[[[1],[]],[]],
(new Array(10))[1] = 0,
false,
true,
"  ",
```

### Rewrite

With the above assumptions you can rewrite the code as a two functions.

As a non empty object mean we return false, and thus we do not need to iterate its values.

The entry point is `isItemEmpty` you would call it as you did `isDeepEmpty`

```
const isObjEmpty = obj => obj === null || Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
const isItemEmpty = item => item === undefined || item === "" ||
    (Array.isArray(item) && item.every(isItemEmpty)) ||
    (typeof item === "object" && isObjEmpty(item));
```

Usage

```
isItemEmpty([{},[],[[]]]);    // returns true
isItemEmpty([{A:0},[],[[]]]); // returns false
isItemEmpty("");              // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my improved version.

- it builds on top of `isEmpty()`
- correctly treats `undefined` in my test cases (tricky as `undefined` is not an object unlike `null`)
- `isDeepEmpty([0]) = true` and return values for other test cases are pretty intuitive
- `isDeepEmpty(42) = false`, but `isEmpty(42)` behaves the same way

Here:

```
import isEmpty from 'lodash/fp/isEmpty'

export function isDeepEmpty(input) {
  if(isEmpty(input)) {
    return true
  }
  if(typeof input === 'object') {
    for(const item of Object.values(input)) {
      // if item is not undefined and is a primitive, return false
      // otherwise dig deeper
      if((item !== undefined && typeof item !== 'object') || !isDeepEmpty(item)) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  return isEmpty(input)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**My review**

- the presented code is not generic enough to handle what can be considered as an empty value;
- the check `if (!input) return true` is not robust for all possibile use cases of what can be considered as `null`, `undefined`, or empty;

**Alternative solution**

This version, differently that last proposed solution, it avoids to use `lodash` library, thus recursively calling an `empty` function (inspired to the PHP `empty`), that supports as input a empty values list `emptyValues`, in order to explicitly define what is empty, like `[undefined, null, '']` or `[undefined, null, '', 0]`:

```
function emptyDeep(mixedVar, emptyValues = [undefined, null, '']) {
    var key, i, len
    for (i = 0, len = emptyValues.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (mixedVar === emptyValues[i]) {
            return true
        }
    }
    if (typeof mixedVar === 'object') {
        for (const item of Object.values(mixedVar)) {
            if (!emptyDeep(item, emptyValues)) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Examples:

```
emptyDeep([{},[],[[]]]);
true
emptyDeep([{A:0},[],[[]]])
false
emptyDeep([{A:0},[],[[]]],  [undefined, null, '', 0])
true
emptyDeep({x:[{},[],[[]]]})
true
emptyDeep(0, [undefined, null, '']);
false
emptyDeep(0, [undefined, null, '', 0])
true
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].